# Is it possible to make android webview based app less sensitive in interpreting taps as small drags?

Tags: android, reactjs, xamarin, webview, touch

I have and C# Xamarin **android** app that hosts a reactjs app in a **webview**.

When using this app on a touch screen android device, It appears that occasionally tapping the screen is ignored.

What appears to be going on is that, the tap is interpreted as a mini drag event, as there was some small directional movement in the tap.

Looking at the **android** logs, for failed taps, I noticed output like the following:

```
adb -d logcat -s CustomFrequencyManagerService

06-19 13:35:49.225  2945  9989 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 839000  uid : 1000  pid : 2945  pkgName : GESTURE_DETECTED@CPU_MIN@49
06-19 13:35:49.781  2945  2945 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 839000  uid : 1000  pid : 2945  tag : GESTURE_DETECTED@CPU_MIN@49
```

Note the `GESTURE_DETECTED` part of the log entry.

However for successful taps, CustomFrequencyManagerService has no output in the log.

Looking at this from the **reactjs** app perspective:

I noticed that the failed taps emit the following events:

```
touchstart
touchend
```

While the normal successful events are:

```
touchstart
touchend
mousedown
blur
mouseup
click
```

I could potentially change the reactjs app to respond directly to touch events instead of click events, but I was wondering **if there was a way** (hopefully programmatically via android app) **to alter the sensitivity with regard to what's interpreted as a drag as opposed to a click**?

By installing a `IOnTouchListener` on the `Android.WebKit.WebView`

```
_webView.SetOnTouchListener(new GestureIgnoreTouchListener());
```

I was able to see at what movement threshold a click turned into a drag.

```
    public class GestureIgnoreTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        float _x;
        float _y;

        public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                _x = e.RawX;
                _y = e.RawY;
                
                return false;
            }
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                var diffX = e.RawX - _x;
                var diffY = e.RawY - _y;

                var distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(diffX, 2) + Math.Pow(diffY, 2));
                // observed: 
                // if distance is 10 or less then this is interpreted as a click.
                // if distance is 12 or greater, click is not emitted.
                Console.WriteLine(distance);

                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Ideally, if the distance was between 10 and 50, I would like to be able to make this be considered a click not a drag. Possibly I could create a synthetic click event, in this case, but I'm hoping I can somehow influence what ever android code is responsible for interpreting this as a drag.

Comment: You could set `OnDragListener` and check if it was not a drag, pass the event to `OnClickListener`

Comment: (thanks for the suggestion) Only the TouchListener appears to work with webview. The Drag + Click ones never appear to be invoked. (I see other SO posts that suggest the same think - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600017/setonclicklistener-not-response-on-android-webview)

Comment: Have you tried creating the drag/swipe gesture recognizer and assigning a threshold value? This might make anything less than the assigned value be interpreted as a tap. hopefully 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches I've seen people use for this situation. The first you already mentioned: tell react when you're in touch screen environment to use tap events instead of click events.

The second is to take into account what Android refers to as "**touch slop**":

From https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html:

> Because finger-based touch isn't always the most precise form of
> interaction, detecting touch events is often based more on movement
> than on simple contact. To help apps distinguish between
> movement-based gestures (such as a swipe) and non-movement gestures
> (such as a single tap), Android includes the notion of "touch slop".
> Touch slop refers to the distance in pixels a user's touch can wander
> before the gesture is interpreted as a movement-based gesture. For
> more discussion of this topic, see Managing Touch Events in a
> ViewGroup.

Google provides an example of one way to deal with it in a difference context here: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup#vc which you could probably adapt to your situation.

Comment: thank you - at least now I know what the concept is called.